# jQuery DataTable - Server-side processing

Tags: jquery

I read 100 data from Database, but I send only 10 data to DataTable. But I want use Server-side processing from http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side.

My code is:

```
function prepareDataTable() {
$('#displayData').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "iDisplayStart": 20,
    "aaData": Rows,
    "iTotalRecords": 57,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 57,
    "bSort": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "name" }
    ]
});
```

In Rows I have only 10 data. So I want use Ajax to pass next data. And I want:

1. I want display "Showing 1 to 10 of iTotalRecords entries", where iTotalRecords is number of all my data.
2. Arrows next / previous will be enable (now are disable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first use server side script by which you can get the json format data then your code becomes more like the following:

```
$('#displayData').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
    ...etc option
});
```

In `server_processing.php`, use options according to your requirements to get your data.

For more help see [server side datatable](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).